# How stop endless default loop switch in C

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I am writing a code for university. We should use enum and switch case.
The user gives a number from 1-7. The result is `{doe=1, re, mi, sol, fa, la, si, default= different number}`.

However, I thought the default should come every time something different from 1-7 appears, but when the user types any letter or text, the program starts an infinite loop. How can I correct that?

I have tried the `!isdigit()`, but I still have the same problem.

Below you can see the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main (){
enum tast{doe = 1, re, mi, fa, sol, la, si}taste;
int opt;

 do{
    printf("Geben Sie ein Zahl zwischen 1 und 7 ein: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%u", &taste);

    /*
     *
     *   if(!isdigit(taste)){
     goto exit_loop;
    }
    exit_loop:
     *
     */

   switch(taste){
   case doe:
        printf("doe");
        break;
   case re:
        printf("re");
        break;
   case mi:
        printf("mi");
        break;
   case fa:
        printf("fa");
        break;
   case sol:
        printf("sol");
        break;
    case la:
        printf("la");
        break;
    case si:
        printf("si");
        break;
    default:
        printf("--");
        break;
    }

printf("\n\nPressen Sie '0', um das Programm zu schliessen: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &opt);

    printf("\n");

    }while( opt!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is because the letter is not processed and remains in the input buffer, so next time it is still not processed. Consider obtaining input with `fgets` into a string and apply `sscanf` to that string. if it fails, input another string.

Comment: Rather than `re, mi, sol, fa, la, si`, I would expect `re, mi, fa, sol, la, si`

Comment: @hanie that is horrible: the more you try to hedge around the way scanf works, the worse it gets.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know it's strange ,but it works, yet I think you're right and I don't why it works?

Comment: When i tried something like {sscanf(taste,"%u", 100);} it asks for a breakpoint. However after reading a little bit more abount fgets and sscanf I came across with "getchar()". If I write it below the {scanf function} the problem is gone.